# How come I can add the second middleware in my NodeJS code without adding next() method

Tags: node.js

I am just writing a small NodeJS code with express module. It was said that we can't continue our request to next middleware without using next() method. But, I am able to continue the request to next middle ware without using next().

```
            //III Party
            const express =  require('express');

            // returns express app
            const app = express();

            app.use('/add',(req,res,next)=>{
                console.log('Add Middleware');    
                res.send('Add product');    
            });

            app.use('/delete',(req,res,next)=>{
                console.log('delete Middleware');    
                res.send('Delete Product');    
            });

            // Middle Ware
            app.use('/',(req,res,next)=>{
                console.log('First Middleware');    
                res.send('Hello World');    
            });

            app.listen(3000);
```

Kindly explain me this.[This is the output for my "/delete" request which is handled in second middleware(without using next methode in previous middleware)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckxVQ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is totally correct.

Your so called "First Middleware" is actually the last middleware.

I guess you misthought the hierarchy of the path determine the order of middlewares, from `/` then `/a` then `/a/b` then `/a/b/c`... But this is not the case.

In fact, **the order you call `app.use` determines the priority of the middlewares**.

Quote from http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.use

> Middleware functions are executed sequentially, therefore the order of middleware inclusion is important.

```
// this middleware will not allow the request to go beyond it
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('Hello World');
});

// requests will never reach this route
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Welcome');
});
```

When you get `/delete`, it searches for the first middleware that matches the path, that is

```
       app.use('/delete',(req,res,next)=>{
            console.log('delete Middleware');    
            res.send('Delete Product');    
        });
```

Since you didn't call `next()`, any subsequent middleware that matches the path will not be called. i.e.

```
        app.use('/',(req,res,next)=>{
            console.log('First Middleware');    
            res.send('Hello World');    
        });
```

is not called.

That's why you see `Delete Product` in the response text but not `Hello World`.
 You can experiment yourself by changing the order of `app.use` and adding or removing `next()` to see different results.

Comment: So, if I keep the order same and call '/' middleware it won't work. Right?

Comment: If you request "/", it will print "Hello World". Since it is the only middleware that matches the path "/". The middleware functions added before it wouldn't matter since they do not match the path.

Comment: that helped...Thank You.